# JPA and order warranty

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I use jpa.

I have a rent object who contain a list of payment. (one to many relation).

In database for rent

```
rentId
1
2
3
```

For payment

```
paymentId, payment, rentId
1          20       1
2          20       2
3          15       3
4          10       2
```

Is it warranty with JPA then if we get a rent, list of payment will be ordered by paymentId?

Like if i get rent, is it warranty then in the payment list i get list 2, 4 and not 4 and 2?

Comment: where is your class and annotations/XML ? There are two different ordering routes that any JPA docs would tell you about

Answer (score 1):

There is an annotation [`@OrderBy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OrderBy.html), which can be used to specify the order of the items in the collection. The Javadoc contains the following:

> If the ordering element is not specified for an entity association, ordering by the primary key of the associated entity is assumed.

So, if you do not specify the order, it will be ordered by the primary key, which I assume is `paymentId` in your case.